# How do I keep background jobs from telling me they're done

Tags: bash, rvm

In RVM (Ruby Version Manager) you can create `.rvmrc` files for a per-project basis. This handles basic ruby version and library (gem) management. This script is automatically executed when you `cd` into an directory. However, it is nothing more than a Bash script. There is one particular part in the script that is as follows:

```
(
  if ! command -v bundle ; then
    gem install bundler --no-rdoc --no-ri
  fi

  bundle | grep -v 'Using' | grep -v 'complete' | sed '/^$/d'

) &
```

Since this is executed ever time you `cd` into a directory, it would be nice if I didn't get the following every time:

```
[1]+  Done                    ( if ! command -v bundle; then
    gem install bundler --no-rdoc --no-ri;
fi; bundle | grep --color=auto -v 'Using' | grep --color=auto -v 'complete' | sed '/^$/d' )
```

Is there any way that I can run these set of commands in the background and **not** be notified when it is completed. Or at least notified in a less obnoxious way such that the message might be like:

```
[1]+ Bundler is done! :-)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `disown`, for example:

```
sleep 1 & disown
```

From `man bash`:

> `disown [-ar] [-h] [jobspec ...]`
>
> Without options, each jobspec is removed from the table of active jobs. If jobspec is not present, and neither -a nor -r is supplied, the shell's notion of the current job is used. If the -h option is given, each jobspec is not removed from the table, but is marked so that SIGHUP is not sent to the job if the shell receives a SIGHUP. If no jobspec is present, and neither the -a nor the -r option is supplied, the current job is used. If no jobspec is supplied, the -a option means to remove or mark all jobs; the -r option without a jobspec argument restricts operation to running jobs. The return value is 0 unless a jobspec does not specify a valid job.

Comment: Works great! The only issues is that it shows me the command it is disowning. Not a big deal but, I'd like to hide that too if possible. :-)

Comment: `(sleep 1 & disown) 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect all output to either a logfile or to /dev/null too. Simply change the last line from

```
) &
```

to

```
) 2>&1 >>/var/log/rvm-log &
```